# C++ - Attempting to use string functions to reverse an input string

Tags: c++, string, namespaces, reverse

As part of a homework assignment I need to be able to take an input string and manipulate it several ways using a list of string functions. The first function takes a string and reverses it using a for loop. This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace hw06
{
    typedef std::string::size_type size_type;

    //reverse function
    std::string reverse( const std::string str );

}


// Program execution begins here.

int main()
{
    std::string inputStr;

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, inputStr );


    std::cout << "Reversed: " << hw06::reverse( inputStr )
    << std::endl;


    return 0;
}


//reverse function definition

std::string hw06::reverse( const std::string str )
{

    std::string reverseStr = "";
//i starts as the last digit in the input. It outputs its current 
//character to the return value "tempStr", then goes down the line
//adding whatever character it finds until it reaches position 0
    for( size_type i = (str.size() - 1); (i >= 0); --i ){
        reverseStr += str.at( i );
    }
        return reverseStr;
}
```

The program asks for input, then returns this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>    what(): basic_string::tat

I'm really at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here. The loop seems correct to me, so am I misunderstanding how to reference the function?

Comment: random guess: size_type is unsigned, so (i >= 0) will always be true, and i underflows.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code to see what is going wrong in your reverse function.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin your guess isn't random at all. `std::string::size()` returns `size_t` which the standard requires be an unsigned type.

Comment: +1 to you and your instructor for using `std::string`.

Comment: I suppose, being homework, you're disallowed from using `std::reverse`  from `<algorithm>`?

Comment: +1 for using `std::string`, -1 for passing a string by value *and* `const` (unless that is a typo and it was meant to be `const std::string&`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your loop never terminates.  You have as your condition `i >= 0`, but size_type is unsigned, so `0 - 1 == 2^(sizeof(size_t) * 8) - 1`, which is certainly out of the range of your string.  Therefore, you need to pick something else as your termination condition.  One option is you can use `i != std::string::npos`, but that feels wrong.  You're probably better off with something like:

```
for (size_type i = str.size(); i != 0; ) {
    reverseStr += str.at(--i);
}
```

**EDIT:**  I did some checking on `i != std::string::npos`.  It should be well-defined and OK.  However, it still seems like the Wrong Way To Do It.

Comment: That did it! It shaves off the last letter (since the first letter in the string will be i = [0]), so I just added this line: reverseStr +=str.at( 0 );

Comment: Uhm... this code shouldn't shave anything and should run as is. If it doesn't, you copy-pasted it wrong.

Comment: my intuition tells me that this is one of the less elegant answers in this thread, although it will probably work fine. In a productive environment, where your code has to be maintainable above all else, you may want to avoid ominous side effects in function parameters though :)

Comment: random guess at copy-paste error: changed predecrement to postdecrement, keeping i initialized to str.size()-1?

Comment: ominous side effects? I don't think using predecrement counts as an ominous side effect - it's a pretty commonly accepted idiom.  And it's certainly more elegant than decrementing i AND subtracting 1 in the parameter.  The most effective solution is to use reverse iterators, but as I said in a comment on @JerryCoffin's answer I don't think that's what the teacher is looking for...

Comment: @RobertMason I was refering to the decrement operator as part of the assignemnt. It's fine in this simple case, but I've seen more complex code from people that made this a habit, and it was not pretty.

Comment: If you have complex expressions like that you should probably break it up into multiple statements... I don't think that that's a failing of the pre{inc,dec}rement operators so much as a putting too much logic in a single statement, *especially* when the order of the execution of the subexpressions is undefined.  I see no reason to call a simple statement like the above that any half-decent C programmer can understand 'ominous' because it can be abused, but we can agree to disagree.

Comment: Where did you find in the standard that using `std::string::npos` is fine? I could not find a quote anywhere defining what the value of `std::string::npos` is. [EDIT: Found it, 21.4/5 `static const size_type npos = -1;`]

Answer (score 5):

Unless you really *want* to write a loop, it's probably easier to just do something like:

```
std::string reverse(std::string const &input) { 
    return std::string(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
}
```

Comment: That *is* the right way to do it, but the OP says it's homework and I doubt many teachers would like that - if they're just learning to reverse strings they probably haven't gone over iterators.

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it! Unfortuantely, this is a homework assignment with the purpose of making us use a small library of functions to recombine them in novel ways. rbegin and rend would have been ideal here :(

Answer (score 2):

As Andreas Grapentin said, the problem is that `std::string::size()` returns a `size_t` which is required by the standard to be an unsigned type. So it will *always* be `>= 0` and when you hit `0` and decrement it, you will go to some really large, positive number.

Consider something like this:

```
std::string hw06::reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string reverseStr;

    for(size_t i = str.size(); i != 0; i--)
        reverseStr += str.at(i - 1);

    return reverseStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not keen on answering homework questions, but seeing some of the answers, I couldn't resist this:

```
std::string hw06::reverse(const std::string &str)
{ return std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend()); }
```

Simple, clean and least wasteful if you can't do it in-place.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, the problem is in the loop. I'll suggest using the following "goes to" operator :)

```
for(size_t i = str.size(); i --> 0;)
{
}
```

Comment: isn't this the same as `(i--) > 0`? if so, I don't think that's good practice.

Comment: *Clever* - but **very likely** to confuse someone who is clearly learning the language and will not be easily able to decipher this code and assume that there actually is a magical "goes to" operator. You may want to provide an explanation. @AndreasGrapentin yes, it is and you are right.

Answer (score 0):

use i-- and not --i. Or u will decrease i value before getting the char and get loop problems.